# Cannot load mod_jrun20.so on Windows/ Coldfusion 6.1

Tags: coldfusion, apache2, coldfusion-6

I'm moving a server on a dying W2k server over to a temporary W2K8 server which happens to be running ColdFusion MX6.1. Whilst trying to get Apache 2.2 to load the coldfusion module, I'm getting the following error:

Cannot load... mod_jrun20.so into server: The specified procedure could not be found. Note the errors or messages above, and press the ESC key.

I've deleted and recreated the Connector configuration file for Apache to no avail. Any ideas?
I've applied the 6.1 Updater 3.

Answer (score 0):

For Apache 2.2, you'll need mod_jrun22.so. If all you have is mod_jrun20.so, you'll need to downgrade Apache to version 2.0.x